# How to get PromptDialog.Choice features and still allow other User responses in Bot Framework?

Tags: c#, botframework

The PromptDialog.Choice in the Bot Framework offers a lot of built in functionality that is working well. However, I would like to be able to intercept / override the matching process.

What's the best way to get the PromptDialog.Choice functionality and yet also be able to accept certain strings that may not be a match?

Example:

Bot: What else can I help you with?

- Option 1
- Option 2
- Option 3

Then allow user to enter a command or number that bypasses the options above, without triggering the retry error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think on two alternatives:

1. Create your own PromptChoice dialog and override the TryParse logic to handle those strings that may not be a match. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/d0d188c682b7ad6656ef0eb874622ccdc88d251b/CSharp/demo-Search/Search.Dialogs/CancelablePromptChoice.cs) is an example of a 'CancelablePromptChoice' that basically recognize some cancelTerms that will allow the user to exit the PromptChoice without selecting any of the options.
2. Use [Facebook's quick replies](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/quick-replies) but the drawback is that you will have to write some of the logic that is already in place in the PromptChoice. [Here](http://southworks.com/blog/2016/09/15/sending-facebooks-quick-replies-using-microsoft-bot-framework/) is an example of using Facebook's quick replies with the Microsoft Bot Framework that I wrote a few weeks ago.

Comment: Thanks - this is along the lines of what I was thinking would be necessary. Example code is really helpful.