# How to avoid PromptChoice Retry Message

Tags: c#, botframework

Very similar question to this one: [How to get PromptDialog.Choice features and still allow other User responses in Bot Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39876858/how-to-get-promptdialog-choice-features-and-still-allow-other-user-responses-in?rq=1)

I want to extend the PromptChoice to give a user a number of options, something like this:

Here's what I found:

Option 1
Option 2
Option 3

Which do you want information on?

If the user responds with "Option 1", I'd like to use the PromptChoice to pick it. But if the user responds with more natural language, something like "Where is Option 1"? even though the out of the box PromptChoice does not handle this question, I'd like to respond given information I have on Option 1.

I understand that I have to override the TryParse, but what I'm confused about is how to parse the message myself, and then pick the right option out of the list of options. What do I have to override in PromptChoice to add this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First have a look to the `PromptChoice` implementation and its `TryParse` method, [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L965)

You will see that it is made in 3 recognition steps:

- Recognize choices (trying to recognize the possible choices you provided)
- Recognize numbers ("number 1", "choice 3", etc)
- Recognize ordinals (like "first value", "last choice", etc)

Those steps will provide a `topScore` and `topEntity`, and the best of these 3 values is returned (if the `topScore` is superior to a `minScore` value).

Note that each recognition can be disable in PromptChoice setup, and the `minScore` value can also be setup there.

**How to edit the behaviour?**

One idea would be to set a `minScore` value quite high, and to add an `else` statement to do your dedicated code inside.

That would be:

```
if (topScore >= this.minScore && topScore > 0)
{
    result = topEntity;
    return true;
}
else
{
    // Your custom code here
    // You have access to your list of options, to your message...
}
```

I cannot add more details about what to do in `your custom code here` as your question is not clear enough about that. If it is "known fixed questions" it will be a lot easier than understand all natural language possibilites.